# Informing the mat-table that it should expand to fit the mat-cells?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I've increased the width of `mat-cell` elements like this:

```
.mat-cell {
  min-width: 8rem;
}
```

This causes the cells total width to expand beyond the viewport width, which in turn causes it to overflow the `mat-table`.
How do we get the `mat-table` to dynamically increase its size to fit the cells?  Right now it looks like it only expands by default to the width of the viewport.

[Here's a stackblitz demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-demo-overflow?file=src/styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution.  It makes the table container scrollable.

Add `overflow: auto`;

```
.mat-table { width: 100%; overflow: auto}
```